# Eclipse 4.12 build-in autocompletion has less features?

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, eclipse-2019-06

The build-in autocompletion in eclipse 2019-06 (4.12) doesn't consider gaps in the typed class and method names. In eclipse Photon (4.8) this was working properly. Is this feature no longer available?

I have restored the preferences shown in Java >> Editor >> Content Assist >> Advanced to Default. The problem is still there.

```java
JButton button = new JButton();
button.setBorderPainted(true);
```

Typing *button.setPainted* and pressing [CTRL] + [SPACE] shows no results. The method *setBorderPainted(boolean)* should be proposed.

EDIT:
Installing the plug-in *eclipse Code Recommenders 2.5.4* [1] has solved this issue.

[1] https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.recommenders

Comment: Have you looked through the values on the non-Advanced Content Assist preference page?

Comment: I have checked those preferences too. I thought _Show substring matches_ would be the right option, but it is already activated.

Comment: In Eclipse 2019-03 [Code Recommenders](https://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/) has been removed. Does _Restore Defaults_ in _Window > Preferences: Java > Editor > Content Assist_ and in _... > Advanced_ fix your issue?

Comment: Restoring the default didn't help. Installing the plug-in _Code Recommenders 2.5.4_ using the marketplace solved the issue.

Comment: "In Eclipse 2019-03 Code Recommenders has been removed."
Why do they remove such a great feature?